# Can´t create mysql collation including different alphabets

Tags: mysql, unicode, collation

I am trying to create a mysql collation with which you can search with transcriptions for cyrillic letters.
Here an example: If I send the sql command

*SELECT "w"="в" COLLATE utf8_myowncollation_ci*

the answer should be "1" as "w" would be a transcription for "в".
Here the transcription code I produced:

```
      <collation name="utf8_myowncollation_ci" id="100">
        <rules>
         <reset>\u0077</reset>
         <t>\ud0b2</t>
        </rules>
      </collation>
```

Somehow it still responses "0" anyone has any idea why?

Comment: I guess no one has a solution and this is a bug in the mysql software?

Answer (score 0):

After reading [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/ldml-collation-example.html), I would say that equivalent characters should be wrapped inside a `<i>` tag (instead of `<t>`) but in fact I really do not know what I am talking about.